# Very strange Visual Studio 2013 issue

Tags: .net-4.5, visual-studio-2013

Hi all I wonder if someone out there can help. I have a very strange issue in VS2013, I have a MVC .net4.5 web application. When I try to reference anything from that same project I can't see anything from the entire project. For example if I wanted to reference TestModel in the Models folder in my HomeController I can't find anything. Doing ProjectName.Models.TestModel, produces errors when I try to build the solution.

Any ideas? I've searched around the web but haven't been able to find anything!

Comment: Have you tried to use not ProjectName.Models.TestModel but Models.TestModel

Comment: is your projects debug configuration is set to "Any CPU" or both project have same debug configuration...???

Comment: Yes tried Models.TestModel but still can't access anything. I can see my models in my other project fine!

Comment: You may try to: open object browser, find type you need, right-click -> copy, then paste into you controller as constructor name, for example. If you have correct reference to project which stores model it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue that someone else has experienced: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac8c38cc-d3e1-4649-9b34-8c7cb4f9095f/in-vs-2013-web-applications-cannot-reference-their-own-classes?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Looks like deleting the .suo fixed it!